# getFragmentManager null la segunda vez

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Buenos días, llevo unas semanas programando en Android y estoy teniendo ciertos problemas con el uso de `getFragmentManager`.

He leido post sobre la terminación de actividades y esto es lo que he sacado en claro:

[Cita respuesta Stack Over Flow Ingles 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847526/what-exactly-activity-finish-method-is-doing)

> Además onDestroy() no es un destructor. En realidad no destruye el objeto es solo un metodo que entrega un determinado estado.

además de esto:

[Cita respuesta Stack Over Flow Ingles 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727173/support-fragmentpageradapter-holds-reference-to-old-fragments/9745935#9745935)

> Considerar entonces que su aplicación estara en background y luego muere. Cuando vuelvas Android recordara que tenias Fragments, por ejemplo A, B y C y el gestor los recreara y luego los agregara.

Llamo al metodo 2 veces desde una de mis actividades, y la segunda vez (tras hacer un `getActivity.finish()`, recrear la actividad y volver al método del fragmento anterior), me apunta a null.

El punto de fallo es:

```
        private BroadcastReceiver estadoIAReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    //Cuando cambia el estado de indoor atlas actualizo la interfaz con sus propiedades
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("VFragment", "Cambio estado IA");

        //Ejecutar metodo de un fragment desde una actividad
        infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout); // <<--- AQUI!!!
        infoF.actualizaInfoEstadoIA();
        infoF.onResume();
    }
};
```

E `infoF` es lo que da `null`

```
infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);
```

Esto me devuelve `null`

He estado debuggeando la app y la re-creación de actividades y `fragments` es correcta, por lo que no debería apuntar a `null`.

Mi pregunta es:

Con lo leído, he intuido que está intentado apuntar al antiguo `fragment` (1 vez ejecutada), puesto que `finish`() realmente no borra al 100% la `Activity` (y asumo que `fragments` tampoco). ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está en español

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Mario. En esta sección es obligatorio el uso del español a la hora de redactar las preguntas así como para responder a las mismas. Te recomiendo traducir tu pregunta o moverla a la sección de habla inglesa. Un saludo.

Comment: @eferion Añadiría que estamos en Stackoverflow en español. Stackoverflow simplemente es el sitio por defecto, el inglés. Aunque creo que con ambos comentarios se entiende perfectamente.

Comment: @MarioLópezBatres publica tu pregunta en inglés en: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Si manejas el ingles preguntalo alli. Suele ser mas efectivo

Comment: Gracias! Estoy esperando a los 90 min para volver a preguntar. Un saludo

Comment: @MarioLópezBatres puedes dejar el codigo donde haces el finish?

Comment: Tratas de obtener la referencia de un fragmento dentro de onReceive, debes asignar el correcto contexto para obtener la Activity donde esta siendo inflado el layout que tiene tu Fragment.  Mas tarde entro a responder... estoy aún en medio de un sueño haha :)

Comment: yo creo que podrias establecer unas banderas ahi para que cuando ingreses saltes directamente a la pagina que quieras.

Comment: ¿Podrías aclararme lo del contexto @Elenasys? He estado leyendo y onReceive() necesita un context cada vez que un nuevo evento difundido por el sistema entra, pero no me queda claro como hacerlo.

Yo al método onReceive le paso un Context y un Intent. ¿No sería suficiente? 
**  private BroadcastReceiver coordenadasAEnviarReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {**

Comment: el problema es que si el context que le mandas es el de un Activity que le haces un finish yo creo que se ese context se vuelve null y es por lo que falla.

Comment: ¿Al recrear la actividad no debería crearse un nuevo contexto? La actividad se recrea, al igual que los fragments (he seguido el debbuger para comprobarlo). Pero al intentar  acceder desde el onReceiver me devuelve null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente resolví mi problema. Al parecer, al hacer un finish() no destruyes completamente la actividad, sino que en savedInstanceState se guarda cierta información, y por ello al intentar apuntar al Fragment, devuelve un null.

La solución es la siguiente:

- Tan sólo crea una nueva variable tipo Bundle como una variable global:

  Bundle datosGuardados;
- Para almacenar la información de savedInstanceState

  datosGuardados = savedInstanceState;
- Y comprueba que dicha variable no sea null antes de llamar a getFragmentManager

  if (datosGuardados != null) infoF = (InformacionFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.posicionamiento_layout);

Answer (score 0):

**Al llamar `finish()` se destruye completanente la Activity, pero antes se llama (si es que esta implementado) el método [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))**, que es donde puedes guardar valores deseados, como ejemplo guarda el valor del usuario:

```
  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        savedInstanceState.putString("username", user);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

en este caso se puede utilizar también para saber si previamente existía una instancia, y además se obtiene el valor guardado mediante [onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)), ejemplo :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lomasvisto);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //Obtiene valor guardado en onSavedInstanceState, y necesitado en el Fragment
            String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, MyFragmento.newInstance(user));
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> **[onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))** Llamado para recuperar el estado por
>   instancia de una actividad antes de ser eliminado para que el estado
>   se pueda restaurar en onCreate (Bundle) o onRestoreInstanceState
>   (Bundle) (el Bundle poblado por este método se pasará a ambos).